# How to mount network Volume in Docker for Windows (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, docker

We're working to create a standard "data science" image in Docker in order to help our team maintain a consistent environment. In order for this to be useful for us, we need the containers to have read/write access to our company's network. How can I mount a network drive to a docker container?

Here's what I've tried using the rocker/rstudio image from Docker Hub:

This works:

`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v //c/users/{insert user}:/home/rstudio/foobar rocker/rstudio`

This does not work (where P is the mapped location of the network drive): 
`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v //p:/home/rstudio/foobar rocker/rstudio`

This also does not work: 
`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v //10.1.11.###/projects:/home/rstudio/foobar rocker/rstudio`

Any suggestions?

I'm relatively new to Docker, so please let me know if I'm not being totally clear.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the remote drive to a local directory? Then you could use the local dir in the docker run command.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please help me to understand how that is different from mapping the network volume onto a "local" drive. In the example above, the network drive is the P:, but Docker won't recognize it.

Comment: No different. I just missed that part in your question. From what I can tell in further reading, Docker doesn't support mapped drives.

Comment: Thanks - that's where I got too. Was hoping somebody figured out a solution.

Comment: Just a quick update for folks looking at this. As near as we've been able to figure out, this is actually not possible. As such, we've deployed our container via a Linux machine in order to solve.

Answer (score 6):

I will write my decision. I have a Synology NAS. The shared folder uses the smb protocol.
I managed to connect it in the following way. The most important thing was to write version 1.0 (vers=1.0). It didn't work without it! I tried to solve the issue for 2 days.

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    container_name: 'redis'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Moscow"

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: celery.dockerfile
    container_name: 'celery'
    command: celery --broker redis://redis:6379 --result-backend redis://redis:6379 --app worker.celery_worker   worker --loglevel info
    privileged: true
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Moscow"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - nas:/mnt/nas
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis

volumes:
  nas:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=user,password=pass,**vers=1.0**
      device: "//192.168.10.10/main"
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is relatively old - but for the sake of others - here is what usually works for me. for use - we use a windows file-server so we use cifs-utils in order to map the drive. I assume that below instructions can be applied to nfs or anything else as well.

first - need to run the container in privileged mode so that you can mount remote folders inside of the container (`--dns` flag might not be required)
`docker run --dns <company dns ip> -p 8000:80 --privileged -it <container name and tag>`

now, (assuming centos with cifs and being root in the container) - hop into the container and run:

**install cifs-utils if not installed yet**
`yum -y install cifs-utils`

**create the local dir to be mapped**
`mkdir /mnt/my-mounted-folder`

**prepare a file with username and credentials**
`echo "username=<username-with-access-to-shared-drive>" > ~/.smbcredentials`
`echo "password=<password>" > ~/.smbcredentials`

**map the remote folder**
`mount <remote-shared-folder> <my-local-mounted-folder> -t cifs -o iocharset=utf8,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000,cache=strict`

now you should have access

hope this helps..

Comment: anyone else can testify to the success of this solution?

Comment: Yes it works, but I had to set my username to username=user@domain.com

Comment: Clearly it was asked how to mount in windows not linux.  How did this bubble to the top of the answers?

Comment: @rantlr because the Linux commands were supposed to be run inside the container

Answer (score 4):

I have been searching the solution the last days and I just get one working.

I am running docker container on an ubuntu virtual machine and I am mapping a folder on other host on the same network which is running windows 10, but I am almost sure that the operative system where the container is running is not a problem because the mapping is from the container itself so I think this solution should work in any SO.

Let's code.

> First you should create the volume

```
docker volume create 
--driver local 
--opt type=cifs 
--opt device=//<network-device-ip-folder>
--opt o=user=<your-user>,password=<your-pw>
<volume-name>
```

> And then you have to run a container from an image

```
 docker run 
 --name <desired-container-name> 
 -v <volume-name>:/<path-inside-container>
 <image-name>
```

> After this a container is running with the volume assignated to it,
>   and  is mapped to .
>   You create some file in any of this folders and it will be replicated
>   automatically to the other.
>
> In case someone wants to get this running from docker-compose I leave
>   this here

```
services:
  <image-name>:
    build: 
      context: .
    container_name: <desired-container-name> 
    volumes:
       -  <volume-name>:/<path-inside-container>
    ...

volumes:
  <volume-name>:
    driver: local
    driver_opts: 
      type: cifs 
      device: //<network-device-ip-folder>
      o: "user=<your-user>,password=<your-pw>"
```

Hope I can help

Comment: This doesn't work for Windows containers. The daemon throws an error due to OS incompatibility: `Error response from daemon: create test_cifs_volume: options are not supported on this platform`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution by @Александр Рублев, the trick that solved this for me was reconfiguring the Synology NAS to accept the SMB version used by docker. In my case I had to enable SMBv3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31949012)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found this when looking for something similar but see that it's receiving comments for others, like myself, who find it.
**I have figured out how to get this to work** for a similar situation that took me awhile to figure out.
The answers here are missing some key information that I'll include, possibly because they weren't available at the time

1. The CIFS storage is, I believe, only for when you are connecting to a **Windows System** as I do not believe it is used by Linux at all unless that system is emulating a Windows environment.
2. This same thing can be done with NFS, which is less secure, but is supported by almost everything.

you can create an NFS volume in a similar way to the CIFS one, just with a few changes. I'll list both so they can be seen side by side

When using NFS on ***WSL2*** you 1st need to **install the NFS service** into the Linux Host OS. I believe CIFS requires a similar one, most likely the `cifs-utils` mentioned by @LevHaikin, but as I don't use it I'm not certain. In my case the Host OS is Ubuntu, but you should be able to find the appropriate one by finding your system's equivalent for `nfs-common` (or `cifs-utils` if that's correct) installation

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nfs-common
```

That's it. That will install the service so NFS works on Docker (It took me forever to realize that was the problem since it doesn't seem to be mentioned as needed anywhere)

---

If using NFS, On the network device you need to have set NFS permissions for the NFS folder, in my case this would be done at the `folder` folder with the mount then being to a folder inside it. That's fine. (In my case the NAS that is my server mounts to `#IP#/volume1/folder`, within the NAS I never see the `volume1` in the directory structure, but that full path to the shared folder is shown in the settings page when I set the NFS permissions. I'm not including the `volume1` part as your system will likely be different) & you want the FULL PATH after the IP (use the IP as the numbers ***NOT*** the HostName), ***according to your NFS share***, whatever it may be.

If using a CIFS device the same is true just for CIFS permissions.

- The `nolock` option is often needed but may not be on your system. It just disables the ability to "lock" files.
- The `soft` option means that if the system cannot connect to the mount directory it will not hang. If you need it to only work if the mount is there you can change this to `hard` instead.
- The `rw` (read/write) option is for ***Read/Write***, `ro` (read-only) would be for ***Read Only***

As I don't personally use the CIFS volume the options set are just ones in the examples I found, whether they are necessary for you will need to be looked into.

- The `username` & `password` ***are*** required & ***must*** be included for CIFS
- `uid` & `gid` are Linux user & group settings & should be set, I believe, to what your container needs as Windows doesn't use them to my knowledge
- `file_mode=0777` & `dir_mode=0777` are Linux Read/Write Permissions essentially like `chmod 0777` giving anything that can access the file Read/Write/Execute permissions (More info Link #4) & this should also be for the Docker Container not the CIFS host
- `noexec` has to do with execution permissions but I don't think actually function here, but it was included in most examples I found, `nosuid` limits it's ability to access files that are specific to a specific user ID & shouldn't need to be removed unless you know you need it to be, as it's a protection I'd recommend leaving it if possible, `nosetuids` means that it won't set UID & GUID for newly created files, `nodev` means no access to/creation of devices on the mount point, `vers=1.0` I think is a fallback for compatibility, I personally would not include it unless there is a problem or it doesn't work without it

In these examples I'm mounting `//NET.WORK.DRIVE.IP/folder/on/addr/device` to a volume named "`my-docker-volume`" in Read/Write mode. The CIFS volume is using the user `supercool` with password `noboDyCanGue55`

**NFS** from the CLI

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=NET.WORK.DRIVE.IP,nolock,rw,soft --opt device=:/folder/on/addr/device my-docker-volume
```

**CIFS** from CLI (May not work if Docker is installed on a system other than Windows, will only connect to an IP on a Windows system)

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=cifs --opt o=user=supercool,password=noboDyCanGue55,rw --opt device=//NET.WORK.DRIVE.IP/folder/on/addr/device my-docker-volume
```

---

This can also be done within Docker Compose or Portainer.
When you do it there, you will need to add a `Volumes:` at the bottom of the compose file, with no indent, on the same level as `services:`

In this example I am mounting the volumes

- `my-nfs-volume` from `//10.11.12.13/folder/on/NFS/device` to "`my-nfs-volume`" in Read/Write mode & mounting that in the container to `/nfs`
- `my-cifs-volume` from `//10.11.12.14/folder/on/CIFS/device` with permissions from user `supercool` with password `noboDyCanGue55` to "`my-cifs-volume`" in Read/Write mode & mounting that in the container to `/cifs`

```
version: '3'
services:
  great-container:
    image: imso/awesome/youknow:latest
    container_name: totally_awesome
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - 1234:5432
    volumes:
      - my-nfs-volume:/nfs
      - my-cifs-volume:/cifs

volumes:
  my-nfs-volume:
   name: my-nfs-volume
   driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.11.12.13,nolock,rw,soft"
      device: ":/folder/on/NFS/device"
  my-cifs-volume:
    driver_opts:
      type: "cifs"
      o: "username=supercool,password=noboDyCanGue55,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noexec,nosuid,nosetuids,nodev,vers=1.0"
      device: "//10.11.12.14/folder/on/CIFS/device/"
```

More details can be found here:

1. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/
2. https://www.thegeekdiary.com/common-nfs-mount-options-in-linux/
3. https://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/5/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-client-config-options.html
4. https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/