# volume docked to another machine

Tags: docker

Good morning to all of you!
I've been using Docker for two months now and I find this technology absolutely brilliant. 
I'm having a little trouble with my container run docker.
I want to mount a Docker volume in my local network and not only in the docker folder of my container in order to expose the configuration files of my application to everyone (a team of developers).
Do you know how to do that, please?

configuration:
linux mint 19.3
Docker 19

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287408/how-to-mount-network-volume-in-docker-for-windows-windows-10

Comment: Docker has no particular out-of-the-box support for this.  If you can mount the drive to your host then you can bind-mount that directory into a container, or if it makes sense to put the files in question into an image then you could push that image to a registry.  Often the best solution is the not-Docker-specific approach of checking these configuration files into source control.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount an NFS, give a review to this article

https://whyistheinternetbroken.wordpress.com/2015/05/12/techusing-nfs-with-docker-where-does-it-fit-in/